# Передача данных из одного файла на другой

Tags: javascript

Как можно передать данные с одного файла на другой? Создаю чат, в первом файле выходит окно с регистрацией(на данный момент пока только имя (бд добавлю позже)), записывается в переменную. Нужно отослать переменную с именем на другой js файл, которые уже работает непосредственно с сервером и отображением второй страницы чата.
Вот получаю данные с формы:

```
FORM.addEventListener('submit', (Event) => {
    Event.preventDefault();
    if (INPUT.value) {
        let name = INPUT.value;
        Event.target.reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ужасно. "**с** файла"?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (INPUT.value) {
    functionFromOtherFile(INPUT.value);
    ...
```

Comment: То есть просто создать функцию отправитель и на другом js файле принять ее?

Comment: @RumeOne Я не понимаю смысла этого предложения. Особенно "принять ее".

Comment: Что делает функция functionFromOtherFile? Я так понимаю она принимает значение переменной и на другой файле я могу принять эту переменную вызвав эту функцию?

Comment: @RumeOne Кхм, кхм. Да.

Comment: Попробовал сейчас сделать ваш способ, не получилось, как должна выглядеть эта функция? Работаю на Node.js(может быть require или импорты помогут)